# Correlation matrix relationship

Tags: matrix, statistics, correlation, covariance

I have 16 difference array of data X1,X2....X16 and I want to calculate the correlations among themselves. This results a 16x16 correlation matrix, C.

If I know the correlation between X1,x9 as well as X9,X16, is it possible to know the correlation between X1 and X16?

Is there any cyclic relationship among 3 different data sets for correlation values.

Thanks

Farhana

Comment: I am not certain, but I think that if all three datasets are linear independent than yes, you can calculate the correlation between X1 & X16 using the known values.

Comment: Is there any equation for this?
let, p(x,y) is the correlation between x and y,and p(1,16) can be obtained from a functional relationship between p(1,9) and p(9,16) i.e.
**p(1,16)=function [ p(1,9), p(9,16) ]**
then what could be functional equation to obtain p(1,16)?